# react-native how to deploy debug version device

Tags: react-native

I am trying to deploy a debug version of app to Android device. After having some issues with python, gradle.build... I was able to install debug version of my app to my device.

What is the command to do live reload on device? I am getting attached error. Here are the steps.  I am following below steps for live reload.

1. on terminal > "react-native run-android --device". This installed debug version of my app in to my device.
2. on terminal> "adb shell input keyevent 82"
3. A pop up is getting displayed on device with different options["Realod JS", "Enable live relaod" etc]
4. Select "Enable Live reload"
5. Modify any file.
6. on terminal> "adb shell input keyevent 82"
7. Select "Reload JS" on pop up which you get in device.

I am getting below error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open dev menu from terminal with command `adb shell input keyevent 82`. And then enable live reload from there.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question with the error I am getting. Thanks.